# Lua Script (Mouse Relative)

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I'm Trying to make a no recoil for a game And Why It doesn't work if I put Mouse Relative (0,10.2) But if make it (0,10) it works

Comment: The arguments to `MoveMouseRelative` must be integers in the range `-127...+127`.  You can't pass `10.2` there.

Comment: The mouse cursor can't be moved fractional amount of pixels :-)  Pixels are always integer.

Comment: So What should I Do ill Put Mouse Relative (0,10) then?

Comment: And If My Value is 34.78 Ill Round it up to 35?

Comment: Yes, you should round up or down.  `MoveMouseRelative(math.floor(x), math.floor(y))`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this might be happening is because `MoveMouseRelavie(x, y, )` only allows integer values and not float values(with decimals) for x-axis and y-axis.